# request post open cart to codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, opencart

I am trying to find out what is similar to the open cart `$this->request->post['permission']` method and what is the same in codeigniter.

I know you have `$this->input->post();` which is posting data.

But then I think you have `$this->input->get();`

Would the input get in codeigniter be closest to `$this->request->post['permission']`

Comment: `$this->input->post('permission');` isnt closest?

Comment: would you use $this->input->get('permission'); or $this->input->get_post('permission');

Comment: Unclear what you want.. If your request `GET`, use `$this->input->get('permission');` or `POST`, use `$this->input->post('permission');`. Do you want use both `GET` and `POST`?

Comment: In open cart they use `$this->request->post['permission']` but unclear on what is codeigniter equivalent.

Comment: With `$this->input->get_post('permission');` fetch an item from either the GET array or the POST

Answer (score 1):

In every request codeIgniter wraps the `$_POST` array and you can get values by calling `$this->input->post('myKey')`. And the same behaviour with `$_GET` array - `$this->input->get('myKey')`.
So, if you want to get values of posted data, you need to call `$this->input->post('myKey')`.